# What is the name of the song in the last episode of shingeki no kyojin season 3 part 2?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

Appears in the anime called Shingeki no Kyojin in season 3 part 2 episode 10, from 21:52 until the episode ends, it's the last episode of the season

Answer (score 5):

The song you are referring to is **T-KT**, the 2nd song on the *"Attack on Titan" Season 3 Original Soundtrack* disc 2, composed by Hiroyuki Sawano.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this one. This is the only thread I could find mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about AOT's episode 59 seasonal ending song (right before "to the other side of the wall"), it says in the credits that the song is "Name of Love" by Cinema Staff.

Answer (score -2):

Linked Horizon - Akatsuki no Requiem

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding a link to the track so the OP can verify if this is correct